# Is Cassandra reading tombstones? What does this trace mean?

Tags: cassandra

I do a select with tracing ON and see:

```
Skipped 0/1 non-slice-intersecting sstables
included 0 due to tombstones [ReadStage-<N>]
```

So is it working to ignore tombstones? The trace:

```
Read 0 live rows and 2 tombstone cells
```

is clear: it is reading tombstones

Comment: A 'tombstone' is a marker that Cassandra uses when it deletes data, because deletes need to be distributes across a network. Consider this scenario: we try to perform a delete for a record that exists across six stores, and then one of the 'delete' actions fails. The system can't easily tell whether that one left-over record is a failed delete, so it may think the record is valid data and redistribute it. The tombstones mark that the record is on its way out until all copies are gone, then the tombstones are deleted. This is normal.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say there was a Column A.

1. You added value x to Column A.
2. Then you deleted Column A.

Instead of immediately deleting value x, Cassandra will add a marker for Column A which is called tombstone. The tombstone is also an individual record in itself just like the original value x.

Let's say the two updates were written in different sstables (Cassandra storage).

Now when you are reading the value, Cassandra will get the value x and the tombstone for Column A. It will see that tombstone was written after the value x so it will not return any value.

> Skipped 0/1 non-slice-intersecting sstables
>   included 0 due to tombstones

This is basically confirming the same.

Comment: For Cassandra, all the records are immutable, there is no `adding a marker for Column A which is called tombstone.`. Instead, C* will create a new record with the tombstone marker and a more recent timestamp. When a query is issued, the engine will find 2 records (one when it was created, the second when it was deleted), and based on the latest timestamp will decide what is the current state of that record.

Comment: By marker I meant a new record but perhaps I can make the language more clear. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

Based on talking to some Cassandra admins:

" Skipping sstables is Cassandra telling us it eliminated the tombstones efficiently, this is ok

" Deleting everything in a partition in general helps ensure Cassandra is not bogged down with tombstones

Comment: "Deleting everything in a partition in general helps ensure Cassandra is not bogged down with tombstones"
Even if you delete a partition it will sill create a tombstone.